# What is the best way to convert special characters to the corresponding HTML Codes with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to convert everything like **spaces, single/double quotes, line break**, etc.

Here is a sample input (Thanks [som_nangia](http://www.slideshare.net/som_nangia/escape-test-3262832)) :

```
Escape Check < &quot;escape these&quot; > <“and these”> <html><tr><td></td></tr></html> 'these will need escaping too' ‘ so will these’ <script>&nbsp;</script>
```

Here are the options I am considering:

`<pre>Escape Check < &quot;escape these&quot; > <“and these”> <html><tr><td></td></tr></html> 'these will need escaping too' ‘ so will these’ <script>&nbsp;</script></pre>`

```
/**
 * Encoding html special characters, including nl2br
 * @param string  $original
 * @return string
 */
function encode_html_sp_chars($original) {
    $table = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    $table[' '] = '&nbsp;';
    $encoded = strtr($original, $table);
    return nl2br($encoded);
}
```

I have tried both [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), but none of them encodes spaces.

Comment: If you want to escape spaces, too, then this is not about “HTML-specific characters” as the heading says. And ‘smart’ single quotes aren’t HTML-specific either. And you need to specify what exactly “etc.” means in your problem description – specifying what should really be done. (And why?)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to make the issue clear-er

Comment: You still have that “etc.” there.

Comment: etc. is for everything I cannot enumerate.... I expect something better than the function encode_html_sp_chars() I proposed.

Comment: To specify a solvable problem, you need to identify which characters are to be converted. Possibly you should do this indirectly by specifying exactly which characters should *not* be converted.

Answer (score 5):

#### Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
```

In your case, please pass two parameters this way:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Thanks to [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) and [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil).

#### Explanation

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with these conversions made. If you require all input substrings that have associated named entities to be translated, use htmlentities() instead.
>
> If the input string passed to this function and the final document share the same character set, this function is sufficient to prepare input for inclusion in most contexts of an HTML document. If, however, the input can represent characters that are not coded in the final document character set and you wish to retain those characters (as numeric or named entities), both this function and htmlentities() (which only encodes substrings that have named entity equivalents) may be insufficient. You may have to use mb_encode_numericentity() instead.

Comment: And pass `ENT_QUOTES` as a second argument

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, just saw that in the doco. Don't think this was always the case

Comment: Both of you, updated the answer with your credits. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Phil: "5.4.0  The default value for the encoding parameter was changed to UTF-8." :-S

Comment: Thanks for your promptly help! For some reasons, htmlspecialchars() and html_entities() doesn't encode spaces to &nbsp;(s) even though get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES) does contain an entry for space.

Comment: Did you try including the two parameters?

Answer (score 0):

This best way is probably

Example:

```
function encode_html_sp_chars($original) {
    $encoded = htmlentities($original, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $encoded = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $encoded);
    return nl2br($encoded);
}
```